# how can get claims parameter from a decoed jwt

Tags: reactjs, jwt, token, decode

I decode a jwt token with jwt-decode in my react app but i can not get claims parameter from that how can i get those? for example i gonna get role from claims params

this is my decode token result :

```
{
  aud: "SampleAudience"
​
  exp: 1564989998
​
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "SuperAdministrators"
​
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "sso_khani"
​
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "sso_khani"
​
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "ab57e777-91b6-4c4e-d709-08d715866555"
​
  iss: "threenine.co.uk"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get result for a particular key like "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" ? What do you want to do with the decoded result

Comment: yes i want get this for add an access for user for view a link or not

Comment: will object keys be always like this?

Comment: maybe , the back-end team said this is true but i can not get key and values of this object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask your back-end team to provide values in a defined key names.
Still you can do,

```
Object.keys(decodedObj).forEach(function (key) {
    let res = key.split("/");
    if (res.length > 1) {
        if (res[length - 1] === 'role') {
            // decodedObj[key] will be your role
        }
        // here you will get role, emailaddress, name, nameidentifier
    }
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you this work and my problem solved , thank you again

Answer (score -1):

decodedOBj["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"] should return SuperAdministrators etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).